# Can a build be deployed to multiple website subdomains but not change user data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, remix.run

I'm working on a project for a client, and I'm building out the front end and back end for their project. I settled on Remix because I'm familiar with React and know JavaScript/TypeScript.

The client wants a website where groups of users or "teams" are separated into their own subdomains with the same version of the "default" template website. For clarity down the pipeline, and as I add more features to the site I need to be able to publish the same build of the "default" site but not change anything about the site. All of the dynamic data is stored on a database, so it should load exactly as it does when the site is reloaded, but I thought I'd ask if I look shortsighted to any of you. With a couple of 10s of 10s of these subdomains, I want to make it easy and concise to patch bugs and bring platform improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use the host header to determine the tenant, e.g., `tenant1.domain.com`. Then use that to connect to the correct database.